# Proving a function is differentiable iff it's differentiable at a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

In my calculus notes I found the following exercise:

> Suppose that $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x)-f(y)=f(x/y)$ for every $x,y\in(0,\infty)$ and $f(1)=0.$

> (a) Show that $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ iff $f$ is continuous  at $1$.

> (b) Show that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ iff $f$ is differentiable at $1$

I already did point (a), but I'm having problems showing point (b). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Just differentiate the given equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take some $x_0\in(0,+\infty)$ and consider $f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(\frac{x}{x_0})}{x-x_0}$. Let's name $u=\dfrac{x}{x_0}$, so when $x\to x_0$ we have $u\to 1$ and then $f'(x_0)=\lim_{u\to 1}\dfrac{f(u)}{ux_0-x_0}=\dfrac{1}{x_0}\lim_{u\to 1}\dfrac{f(u)-f(1)}{u-1}=\dfrac{1}{x_0}f'(1)$